# $ printenv | grep ROS command not found

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ROS kinetic on ubuntu 16.04.

for the command

```
$ printenv | grep
```

and i am getting response as "command not found".

What's the problem? Could you help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253534/$-printenv-%7C-grep-ros--command-not-found/) by [malgudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29206/malgudi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2017-02-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could be missing either `printenv` or `grep`.

What is the output of `which printenv` and of `which grep`?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EGYRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/33719/egyros/) on 2018-02-15**:
i have the same problem .
output of `which printenv` is "/usr/bin/printenv"
and `which grep` is "/bin/grep"

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-16**:
On Ubuntu, `/bin/grep` is provided by the `grep` package. `/usr/bin/printenv` by `coreutils`.

Do you have those pkgs installed? You can check with `dpkg -l | grep 'coreutils\|grep'`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-16**:
Note btw that you can also use `env` to print the currently defined environment variables.